# What are correct permissions for creating directories?

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I'm trying to create a directory and getting `mkdir(): Permission denied` error. I looking at folder where I'm trying to write to and it's folder permissions are set to `775`.  When I update directory permissions to `777`  the `mkdir` succeeds. Is that a good idea to leave the directory open like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is not a good idea to have folders with permission 777, it is a security issue especially if that folder have to do with your web server.

Now why you are experiencing this problem

php uses the web server (commonly user: www-data) user credentials to access the system.

When permission are set to 775 means that 'others' do not have permissions to write in that folder. Some common permissions are

```
777 : anyone can do anything (read, write, or execute)
755 : you can do anything; others can only read and execute
711 : you can do anything; others can only execute
644 : you can read and write; others can only read
```

A solution to your problem it will be to add the user that php uses (e.g www-data) to the group that have access to that file. Although beware if the owner group of the file that you want to access is `root`, it is a bad idea (because of security issues) to add www-data to that group. To avoid that you can create a group (i.e webUsers) in which you can add www-data and give permission to that group over whatever file you want to have access through the web server.

Depending on what you want really to achieve, you can read these 2 Question/Answer from [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

- [What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)
- [What are perfect unix permissions for usual web project directories?](https://serverfault.com/questions/345833/what-are-perfect-unix-permissions-for-usual-web-project-directories)

**UPDATE**

As correctly pointed by @Dave Kok  at the comments :

'When using groups like that make it 2775 so when making a new file it will get the same group as the parent directory, rather than the default group the user is in.'

Comment: When using groups like that make it 2775 so when making a new file it will get the same group as the parent directory, rather than the default group the user is in.

Answer (score 4):

read carefully you will get answer all your questions (of course about ubuntu permitions)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

[image]

Use **700** permissions and set php user as owner( `chown phpuser:phpuser` ) this way is a secured way

[image]

Comment: Is that a good idea to leave a directory open like that? I'm assuming that PHP is running as a "other" user. Maybe adding PHP process to a group would be a better practice and not giving all permissions away to every user on the system.

Comment: Use 700 permissions and set php user as owner( chown phpuser:phpuser ) this way is a secured way

Answer (score -1):

Giving permission(775/777) to folder depend upon what kind of things you are going to do with that folder. Generally, if folder only contents some files which only need to be read then 775 is fine. But, if there is any kind of writing need to do on any folder then it need to be set with 777.